# automatic rollback with liquibase at production-deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, liquibase

Im using the tool liquibase for database changes in a java ee project with the liquibase-maven-plugin. So far I tried it out at my local machine, but need to go the next step at the production.

Local I can do updates, rollback, putting tags as a kind of checkpoint and replacement for backups. The update is already fully automated. Its executed before the projects runs:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.5</version>
  <configuration>
    ..
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And I can do the rollback and put the tags at the command line, like:

```
mvn liquibase:tag -Dliquibase.tag=release1
mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackTag=release1
```

At the poduction server I want everything to go fully automated. Mainly Im interested in db-rollbacks when the deployment fails and I need to go back for a privious version of the project.
Setting the tag should work like described in [How to tag a changeset in liquibase to rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131978/how-to-tag-a-changeset-in-liquibase-to-rollback).

But how do I manage the rollback fully automated?

1. Is it possible to make a goal for rollback as well? If yes: how do I controll when its excuted? I dont want to create by accident a loop in the project that calls update and rollback endless.

The usual practice is: backup1, update, run. If that fails you go back to backup1. Is this automatically possible? Im afraid that once something fails (while running the project), you cant execute the rollback automatically anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to dynamically enable/disable a plugin execution in Maven.  You would have to know in advance whether the update succeeds, which of course you won't.

You can do this is [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), however, by setting a property for success/failure after the update process runs.  And you can wire an Ant script into Maven easily via the [Maven AntRun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).